# 2 meter Mode Options

Tags: vhf

FM seems to be the most popular in the 144 to 148 MHz  Amateur  Band      .Narrow band is used for spectrum conservation .   SSB is also used but is more common on the HF bands .Would SSB provide any  range advantage when taking VHF propagation into Account ?

Answer (score 5):

As you can read in this answer: [Single Side Band AM vs FM](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/6847/single-side-band-am-vs-fm), SSB is more power efficient than FM so normally you should get a greater range using the same power from your transmitter.
But as R2AUK stated you probably will find a lot more people to talk to on 2m FM than on 2m SSB.

Answer (score 0):

From personal experience it will be not easy to find someone who uses CW or SSB on 2 meters on regular basis. Contests are a noticable exception. On the other hand you can find people on a local repeater who might be interested in experimenting not only with CW or SSB, but also with such digital modes as D-STAR, C4FM and DMR.

From what I know SSB doesn't give any advantage in terms of range. In fact FM might have an advantage since the noise usually is amplitude modulated and FM is more immune to it.

Comment: FM is only noise-resistant as long as the received signal is strong enough for the receiver to capture.  If not, the noise being AM doesn't seem to make a big difference (based on my experience of stations barely reaching the repeaters, or repeaters I can barely hear).